# Open Folder Using Default File Explorer

Tags: android

I am trying to open "MyFolder" but it is opening recent files folder.

I have tried many techniques, nothing seems to work.

All are similar to this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + 
File.separator + "MyFolder" + File.separator);

intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");

 startActivity(intent);
```

Is it possible, if yes, how can I do it?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you want to a open specific folder ?

Comment: Yes i want to open a specific folder which is "MyFolder"

Comment: i post my answer u can see

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no standard `Intent` action to "open" a filesystem directory on Android.

Second, the value that you pass to `Uri.parse()` needs to be a string form of a `Uri`, with a scheme. If you are going to create a `Uri` from a `File`, use `Uri.fromFile()`, rather than turning the `File` into a `String` and passing that `String` to `Uri.parse()`.

Third, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not take a `Uri`.

Comment: i tried Uri.fromFile but it did not work.
I think the problem is file-system can't be open using intent. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: @asimmehmood: Integrate [a directory chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35) into your app.

Comment: @CoomonsWare i don't think you understood the problem i don't want to chose a file i just want the user to go to that specific folder in the device's File explorer.
It should leave my app and open File explorer.

Comment: @asimmehmood: You assume that all devices *have* a file explorer, and that you can ask that to open a directory. Neither is true. So, either build the functionality in your app, or skip it and move on to something else.

Comment: i just wanted to know if it is possible. Thanks for your valuable time.